# Set environment variables from a file in Dockerfile

Tags: docker

I know that I can use `ENV` to set environment variables one by one in my Dockerfile.

My question is that, is there a way (other than perhaps adding some script to bashrc in the image) to set the environment variables inside the Dockerfile from a .env file?

**Note**: In case this is not clear enough, I'm not talking about passing variables in `docker run`, I want the container to run with environment variables already set.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than specifying single environment variables on the `docker run` command one by one, you can use [`--env-file`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-environment-variables--e---env---env-file) to specify lots of them via a file.

If you want to push all currently set variables into the container at runtime, use a combination of

```
printenv > env.txt
docker run --env-file env.txt ...
```

If you need the same at container build time, maybe have a command in Dockerfile to copy env.txt into the container and [source](https://linuxize.com/post/bash-source-command/) it from within.

Now as you mention the container is not run locally, you can still set environment variables at runtime using mechanisms like [Kubernetes ConfigMaps](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/).

Comment: Thanks for responding but I clearly mentioned I'm not talking about docker run. I'm not running the image locally to be concerned about docker run.

Comment: I added ConfigMaps. But it seems you want to bake in the variables at container build time. Have you tried my suggestion about adding and sourcing env.txt?

Answer (score 0):

You can do few other things:

- pass to the cli the param **"-e key=val"** to override your environment variables
- mount a volume in which locate a *toto_config.toml* file for example and parse the values with your application
- if your container has this directory, put your env variables file in `/etc/profile.d/`
- otherwise as it has already been said `docker run --env-file envfile`

Comment: Thanks, but question is not about docker run!